# Can you import a separate version of the same dependency into one build file for test?

Tags: scala, sbt

I was thinking this would work but it did not for me.

```
libraryDependencies += "org.json4s" %% "json4s-core" % "3.6.7" % "test"
libraryDependencies += "org.json4s" %% "json4s-core" % "3.7.0" % "compile"
```

Any idea?

Comment: No, you can't. Your test include all your compile classpath.

Comment: Thanks, wonder is the use if the “test”.

Comment: Test scope allows to specify dependencies only needed for tests which should not be part of the package at runtime.

Comment: Though in Maven what you want to do is possible (override version of a dependency in test), I'm surprised it's not possible with SBT. Not a best practice but sometimes you have to.

Comment: @GaëlJ I guess it's possible in sbt with custom configurations https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Advanced-Configurations-Example.html

Comment: There is discussion about deprecating custom configurations in sbt 2.0 https://eed3si9n.com/sbt-drop-custom-config/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test classpath includes compile classpath.

So create different subrojects for different versions of the dependency if you need that.

```
lazy val forJson4s370 = project
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies += "org.json4s" %% "json4s-core" % "3.7.0" % "compile"
  )

lazy val forJson4s367 = project
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies += "org.json4s" %% "json4s-core" % "3.6.7" % "test"
  )
```

---

If you don't want to create different subprojects you can try custom sbt configurations

https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Advanced-Configurations-Example.html

---

An exotic solution is to manage dependencies and compile/run code programmatically in the exceptional class. Then you can have dependencies/versions different from specified in `build.sbt`.

```scala
import java.net.URLClassLoader
import coursier.{Dependency, Module, Organization, ModuleName, Fetch}
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.Quasiquote
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox

val files = Fetch()
  .addDependencies(
    Dependency(Module(Organization("org.json4s"), ModuleName("json4s-core_2.13")), "3.6.7"),
  )
  .run()

val depClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(
  files.map(_.toURI.toURL).toArray,
  /*getClass.getClassLoader*/ null // ignoring current classpath
)

val rm = universe.runtimeMirror(depClassLoader)
val tb = rm.mkToolBox()
tb.eval(q"""
  import org.json4s._
  // some exceptional json4s 3.6.7 code 
  println("hi")
""")
// hi
```

*build.sbt*

```scala
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  scalaOrganization.value % "scala-compiler" % scalaVersion.value % "test",
  "io.get-coursier" %% "coursier" % "2.1.0-M7-39-gb8f3d7532" % "test",
  "org.json4s" %% "json4s-core" % "3.7.0" % "compile",
)
```

Comment: First option to split tests in a separate module is probably the easiest and cleanest, nice trick.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75562485/nosuchmethoderror-scala-tools-nsc-settings-usejavacplscala-tools-nsc-settings
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75621915/reflection-to-call-method-that-had-its-name-changed-in-an-upgrade