# Use another library version for the Test scope at SBT project

Tags: scala, sbt

I have an SBT project with Scala 2.12, with `"za.co.absa" %% abris %% "4.2.0"` as one of the dependencies. Transitively it brings kafka-clients dependency of version 5.3.4-css.

At the same time for tests I'm using `embedded-kafka` dependency: `"io.github.embeddedkafka" %% "embedded-kafka" % "3.4.0" % Test`. And tests are failing with errors (stack trace example):

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.enumOptions(Ljava/lang/Class;)[Ljava/lang/String;
[info]   at kafka.server.KafkaConfig$.<init>(KafkaConfig.scala:1288)
[info]   at kafka.server.KafkaConfig$.<clinit>(KafkaConfig.scala)
[info]   at io.github.embeddedkafka.ops.KafkaOps.startKafka(kafkaOps.scala:34)
[info]   at io.github.embeddedkafka.ops.KafkaOps.startKafka$(kafkaOps.scala:24)
[info]   at io.github.embeddedkafka.EmbeddedKafka$.startKafka(EmbeddedKafka.scala:52)
[info]   at io.github.embeddedkafka.ops.RunningKafkaOps.startKafka(kafkaOps.scala:82)
[info]   at io.github.embeddedkafka.ops.RunningKafkaOps.startKafka$(kafkaOps.scala:75)
[info]   at io.github.embeddedkafka.EmbeddedKafka$.startKafka(EmbeddedKafka.scala:52)
[info]   at io.github.embeddedkafka.EmbeddedKafka$.start(EmbeddedKafka.scala:70)
[info]   at com.careem.pi.optimus.jobs.BaseJobTest.beforeAll(BaseJobTest.scala:32)
```

Using dependencyTree I've figured out that `kafka-clients` is also a dependency coming from `embedded-kafka` with a different version, but it's overriden by dependency coming from `abris`:

```
┆ [info]   |   | +-org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:3.4.0 (evicted by: 5.3.4-ccs)
┆ [info]   |   | +-org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:5.3.4-ccs
```

Can I force SBT for using 3.4.0 version of `kafka-clients` for the Test scope, and 5.3.4-ccs version for the Compile scope?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74311373/can-you-import-a-separate-version-of-the-same-dependency-into-one-build-file-for

Comment: Haven't tried yet but it looks like a exactly the same problem

Comment: Yeah, I hope this should work. Although sometimes things connected with Spark can become trickier. So please for example try the solution with different subprojects and if this works for your use case please leave a feedback here and we'll close this one as a duplicate

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75562485/nosuchmethoderror-scala-tools-nsc-settings-usejavacplscala-tools-nsc-settings https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75621915/reflection-to-call-method-that-had-its-name-changed-in-an-upgrade

Comment: Keep in mind that doing this reduce the reliability of your tests as they won't use the exact same code as production code. Another approach could be to use testcontainers instead of embedded Kafka.

Comment: @AndreiKoch Do you have any updates?