# error: object apache is not a member of package org

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am learning scala on docker, which doesn't have sbt or maven on it, I am facing this error and all of the internet solutions involve sbt or maven, was wondering if this can be handled without sbt or maven.
Wanted to create the jar using

> scalac problem1.scala -d problem1.jar

Error: 
problem1.scala:3: error: object apache is not a member of package org
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext

Code:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.log4j.{Logger,Level}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField,  LongType, StringType}
//import org.apache.parquet.format.StringType

object problem1 {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF)
    //Create conf object
    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("loadData")
    //create spark context object
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val SQLContext = new SQLContext(sc)
    import SQLContext.implicits._

    //Read file and create RDD
    val table_schema = StructType(Seq(
      StructField("TransID", LongType, true),
      StructField("CustID", LongType, true),
      StructField("TransTotal", LongType, true),
      StructField("TransNumItems", LongType, true),
      StructField("TransDesc", StringType, true)
    ))
    val T = SQLContext.read
      .format("csv")
      .schema(table_schema)
      .option("header","false")
      .option("nullValue","NA")
      .option("delimiter",",")
      .load(args(0))
    //    T.show(5)

    val T1 = T.filter($"TransTotal" >= 200)
    //    T1.show(5)
    val T2 = T1.groupBy("TransNumItems").agg(sum("TransTotal"), avg("TransTotal"),
      min("TransTotal"), max("TransTotal"))
    //    T2.show(500)
    T2.show()
    val T3 =  T1.groupBy("CustID").agg(count("TransID").as("number_of_transactions_T3"))
    //    T3.show(50)
    val T4 = T.filter($"TransTotal" >= 600)
    //   T4.show(5)
    val T5 = T4.groupBy("CustID").agg(count("TransID").as("number_of_transactions_T5"))
    //    T5.show(50)
    val temp = T3.as("T3").join(T5.as("T5"), ($"T3.CustID" === $"T5.CustID") )
    //    T6.show(5)
    //    print(T6.count())
    val T6 = temp.where(($"number_of_transactions_T5")*5 < $"number_of_transactions_T3")
    //    T6.show(5)
    T6.show()
    sc.stop
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Why not to choose a Docker image with sbt?
- Anyway, yes, surely you can create a jar from command line using pure Scala without sbt. You should have dependency jars (`spark-core`, `spark-catalyst`, `spark-sql`, `log4j`, maybe some others if needed) and specify classpath manually

```
scalac -cp /path/to/spark-core_2.13-3.3.1.jar:/path/to/spark-catalyst_2.13/3.3.1/spark-catalyst_2.13-3.3.1.jar:/path/to/spark-sql_2.13/3.3.1/spark-sql_2.13-3.3.1.jar:/path/to/log4j-1.2-api-2.17.2.jar -d problem1.jar problem1.scala
```

For example for me the `path/to` is the following:

```
scalac -cp /home/dmitin/.cache/coursier/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-core_2.13/3.3.1/spark-core_2.13-3.3.1.jar:/home/dmitin/.cache/coursier/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-catalyst_2.13/3.3.1/spark-catalyst_2.13-3.3.1.jar:/home/dmitin/.cache/coursier/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-sql_2.13/3.3.1/spark-sql_2.13-3.3.1.jar:/home/dmitin/.cache/coursier/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-1.2-api/2.17.2/log4j-1.2-api-2.17.2.jar -d problem1.jar problem1.scala
```

- Alternatively, somewhere where you have sbt, you can create a fat jar (`sbt assembly`) with all dependencies (or even with your application and all dependencies) and use it

```
scalac -cp fat-jar.jar -d problem1.jar problem1.scala
```

https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly

- One more option is to create sbt launcher for your application

https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Sbt-Launcher.html

[SBT gives java.lang.NullPointerException when trying to run spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74440324/sbt-gives-java-lang-nullpointerexception-when-trying-to-run-spark)

Sbt launcher helps to run application in environments with only Java installed.

- One more option is to manage dependencies with Coursier programmatically

[Can you import a separate version of the same dependency into one build file for test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74311373/can-you-import-a-separate-version-of-the-same-dependency-into-one-build-file-for)

[How to compile and execute scala code at run-time in Scala3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70945320/how-to-compile-and-execute-scala-code-at-run-time-in-scala3)

[How can I run generated code during script runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73911801/how-can-i-run-generated-code-during-script-runtime)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/62f92bb15550d689c50276d90103c16d https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/ff0b07fc93f1b3674723db1247a1467f https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76028146/running-spark-on-sbt-console